# Using joins in nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, join

My application code is follows like this

**Tables**

```
tblPerson
---------
PersonId (PK)
Name

tblAddress
----------
AddressId(PK)
Address

PersonAddress
-------------
PersonId (PK)
AddressId
```

---

**Entity class**

PersonAddresstbl.cs

```
public class PersonAddressl
{
    private int personid;
    private int addressid;
    private string name;

    public virtual int PersonId
    {
        get { return personid; }
        set { personid = value; }
    }

    public virtual int AddressId
    {
        get { return addressid; }
        set { addressid = value; }
    }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

---

**xml file**

PersonAddresstbl.hbn.xml

```
<class name="PersonAddressl">
  <id name="id" column="PersonId">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
  <join table="tblPersonAddress"
      optional="true">
    <key column="PersonId"
        unique="true"/>
    <many-to-one name="Address"
        column="AddressId"/>
  </join>
</class>

<class name="tblAddress">
  <id name="id" column="AddressId">
    <generator class="native"/>
  </id>
</class>
```

the implementation is

```
PersonAddresstbl tbl = new PersonAddresstbl();

Criteria crit = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(PersonAddresstbl));
IList lst = crit.List();
```

returns 0 record.

Can anyone tell me am I in a right path or where I am going wrong?

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: 1) Your mapping 'id' but your class has 'personid' property. 2) why do you have 'tbl' prefix on your tables? this isn't 1990... 3) Your 'personaddress' why is your primary key not both columns? It's a many-to-many.

Comment: @Phil - re (2), It's not necessary to criticize style.

Comment: @j0k - Sure it is :) Helping people improve their styling. 1 Critique at a time.

Comment: @Phill ;) Hurts my eyes, too, but whatever works for them.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what the issue is, but something I always use with nHibernate when troubleshooting is to enable show_sql so I can see the SQL that gets generated (so you can try that in your database query window). See this link for info: [Enable show_sql in nHibernate](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arnona/archive/2011/01/19/tip-of-the-day-for-nhibernate-2-show-sql-and-format-sql.aspx)

Comment: Hi Haukman, Thanks for the reply. I tried with solution you suggested. Will the output pane shows the sql automatically or do I need to use any command for this?

Comment: @pavan - You need to fix your mapping first. They are all over the place.

Comment: It should show it automatically. But as @Phill indicates, your mapping looks a little odd.

Answer (score 0):

What I find strange, is that your class '`Person`' has a property '`AddressId`' which is of type integer, while in your mapping (of the `Person` class - well, it has the strange name PersonAddressl'- you're specifying that you're having a one-to-many relationship with the class '`Address`'.
Next to that, I do not see that you have a class '`Address`'.
And, your database-model has a many-to-many relationship between Person and Address.

You're using the `join` mapping, which enables you to 'merge' data from two database-tables into one class, but your class-model isn't reflecting this.
Have a look at some more information regarding the join attribute here:  http://ayende.com/blog/3961/nhibernate-mapping-join

Check the 'set' out also: http://ayende.com/blog/3943/nhibernate-mapping-set

Comment: Hi,  I referred the article http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/associations.html (7.3.2. Many-to-one) to create the xml file. Do I need to create entity class files something like 

 tblPerson.cs  with personid, name (get,set) and tblAddress.cs with person, address (get,set)

The cs file which whih I have PersonAddresstbl.cs is not required and the xml file should map to tblperson and tblAddress class file.